# BufferedReader not reading entire JSON from HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read a JSON text from a website; I have the URL, and it's connecting fine. My current code is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String input;


                while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(input);

                    Log.d(TAG,j.toString(4));
                }

                br.close();
```

It's not able to read the JSON from the entire HttpsURLConnection, however. Doing a log for Android I see that it's cutting off halfway through. I think it might have something to do with the size of either input or BufferedReader, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: This is the log

Still not getting it after the first suggestion.

```
05-14 17:37:29.070 3707-3755/asundar.sharks D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                          [ 05-14 17:37:29.070  3707: 3707 D/         ]
                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f0411c26ec0, tid 3707


                                                          [ 05-14 17:37:29.120  3707: 3755 D/         ]
                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f040937e280, tid 3755
```

05-14 17:37:29.140 3707-3755/asundar.sharks I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-14 17:37:29.210 3707-3707/asundar.sharks E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
05-14 17:37:29.240 3707-3707/asundar.sharks E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: `RecyclerView: No adapter attached` this could be a different issue.

Comment: It's a different issue. I added the Log just in case. This isn't my issue as of now. I haven't added anything to the RecyclerView yet.

Comment: If thats the case the log is irrelevant in your current issue.

Comment: ... and there is no point adding log messages that you know are not relevant.

Comment: You can't assume that every line you read is a complete JSON object, unless you know more about the server than you've disclosed here. I do find it surprising that no way is apparently provided to contruct a `JSONObject` from an input stream or reader.

Comment: So I tried building a String and converting it to JSON but had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe way:

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
   StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
   String input;

   while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
        b.append(input);                 
   }

   JSONObject j = new JSONObject(b.toString());

   // this should be in finally block
   br.close();
```

**EDIT**

Basically the response is full (base on the code you sent), the issue your facing is just a **Logcat text limit**. **The response is too long** for the Logcat to print, thats why you are seing a collapse in output.

Comment: I tried your method, and nothing showed up on the log. I created an edit to the master post to reflect that.

Comment: In my example I never placed a log here. You can modify it and add a log to confirm. e.g. `Log.d("jsontest",j.toString());` below `JSONObject j...`

Comment: I did, and the Log doesn't show up at all. It's reflected in the edit. I placed a log and nothing showed up.

Comment: If you dont mind pls send me your api privately, my email is in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

As JSONParser will throw error at runtime as parser.parse "End of File exception" for JSON pretty  print issue.

You can try below logic.

```
        String output;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        StringBuilder stBuild = new StringBuilder();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        LOGGER.debug("conn: {}", conn);
        // fetching NC response in form of buffer reader.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        // reading line using bufferReader
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // parsing string into object.
            stBuild.append(output);
            Object obj = parser.parse(stBuild.toString());
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            // casting object into JSONObject
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try CURLing the URL see what the server sends.

Secondly, if you think it is something to do with buffer size swap out the HttpsURLConnection for something like Apache HttpClient and go from there.

Comment: cURL is still only printing out half of the JSON. It's a really long JSON text. What would using Apache do, and how would I use it?

Comment: If cURL is only printing half then I would say the server is only sending part of the response.

Comment: So when I did a non-Android project and did a System.out.println() in Java it printed the entire thing. How can i get that whole thing?

Comment: Could be the server timing out a slow read.  Could be the server behaving differently depending on (for example) the agent string.